If $C\in M_n(\Bbb R)$ has rank $r$, $\dim(\{A\in M_n(\Bbb R)\mid CAC=0 \})=?$
Let $C$ be a $n\times n$ real matrix with rank $r$ and $V_C=\{A\text{ is a real }n\times n \text{ matrix}\mid CAC=0 \}. $
Find the dimension of $V_C$ as a function of $n$ and $r$.
I have figured the answer but only partially. The partial answer is as follows.
Since $r\leq n$ and $CAC=0$, if $A$ is a non-zero matrix we get that $r<n$.
Consider $n=2$ and $r=1$. Let $C=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$. Then $CAC=0$ implies $ a=0$. For this matrix, we get dimension of $V_C=3$. Similarly, for any $n$, if we consider $C$ as a matrix of the form \begin{pmatrix} I_r & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} then we can observe that dimension of $V_C$ is $n^2-r^2$.
From this how to get the dimension for any matrix $C$?
I know the fact that if $C$ is a matrix of rank $r$, then there exists invertible matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that $PCQ=\begin{pmatrix} I_r & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.
But I do not know how to use this fact to complete the proof. Or can the proof be completed using any other technique?

You are on a good path. Note that $V_C = { A | \begin{pmatrix} I_r & 0 \ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} A \begin{pmatrix} I_r & 0 \ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = 0 } $.

Write $A = \begin{pmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} \ A_{21} & A_{22} \end{pmatrix}$. Then the constraint translates to $A_{11} = 0$.

See Dimension of space of matrices $X$ such that $AXB=0$, in terms of the ranks of $A$ and $B$.. In this case, $A\mapsto CAC$ is represented by $C\otimes C^T$ whose rank is $r^2$ and so whose nullity is $n^2-r^2$.

Let $J_r=\begin{pmatrix} I_r & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, and $U,V$ be invertible marices such that $C=UJ_rV$.

$CAC=0\iff J_r(VAU)J_r=0$ hence $\dim(V_C)=\dim(V_{J_r})$.
$\forall X\in M_r(\Bbb R),Y\in M_{r,n-r}(\Bbb R),Z\in M_{n-r,r}(\Bbb R),T\in M_{n-r}(\Bbb R)$:$$J_r\begin{pmatrix}X&Y\\Z&T\end{pmatrix}J_r=0\iff X=0.$$

Therefore, $\dim(V_C)=n^2-r^2$.
